# Using an intent to start new activity from ListActivity

Tags: android

my ListActivity has a button on the bottom that I want to use to fire up a new activity using an intent. When I tried saying `Intent intent = new Intent(this, OtherActivity.class)` I'm getting an error that the constructor is undefined. FWIW, the other activity extends MapActivity. Not sure if that matters...

What do I need to do to get this to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(NameOfYourListActivity.this, OtherActivity.class)
```

Comment: @LuxuryMode I'd definitely look at the link provided by kgiannakakis to get further explanation as to why it wasn't working.

Comment: @LuxuryMode +1... this has been explained a lot of times so I didn't pointed out the reason :) Thanks for the advice. Lol, I was the one who answered the question provided by kgiannakakis XD