# Unable to start intent from within ListActivity OnItemListClick

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to use the OnItemListClick method of ListActivity to launch a new activity with more specific information about the list item. To do this I am using a bundle as advised by the top answer of [How do I pass an object from one activity to another on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906925/android-how-do-i-pass-an-object-from-one-activity-to-another) but no matter what I try the OnItemListClick doesn't seem to do anything. I also tried without passing the bundle thinking that was causing a problem as advised here [Using an intent to start new activity from ListActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5705976/using-an-intent-to-start-new-activity-from-listactivity) and that also does nothing onClick. How am I supposed to make it so when an item in the listview is clicked it returns the object associated with that row and passes it to a new activity?

```
public class TaskList extends ListActivity {

private ArrayList<Task> stuffToDo, completed;
private TaskAdapter t_adapter;
public Button add;
private File saveFile;
private Bundle clickBundle = new Bundle();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_task_list);
    stuffToDo = new ArrayList<Task>();
    completed = new ArrayList<Task>();
    t_adapter = new TaskAdapter(this, R.layout.row_rl, stuffToDo);

    setListAdapter(t_adapter);
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    // Make a bundle and put the Task selected in it then pass this to the
    // intent to start the new activity
    Intent launchIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TaskDisplay.class);
    Log.d("Debug", "Intent made");
    clickBundle.clear();
    clickBundle.putSerializable("Task", stuffToDo.get(position));
    Log.d("Debug", "Task put in bundle");
    launchIntent.putExtras(clickBundle);
    this.startActivity(launchIntent);
    Log.d("Debug", "launched");


}


@Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.addtaskbutton:
        promptUserForInfo();
        t_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        // added for debug
        saveInfo();
        return true;
    case R.id.cleartasks:
        clearTasks();
        t_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
}
```

and my code that is in the more specific activity

```
//      Set the bundle equal to the extra put with the intent
        input = this.getIntent().getExtras();
//      If there are extras(a task) then assign it to the empty task variable
        if (input != null){
            task = (Task) input.getSerializable("Task");
        }
```

Comment: Does your Listener catch the Event at all?

Comment: Have u specified TaskDisplay class in ur Manifest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here this mean you are pointing towards list.

change `Intent launchIntent = new Intent(this, TaskDisplay.class);`

to Intent `launchIntent = new Intent(youractivityname.this, TaskDisplay.class);`

or to `Intent launchIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TaskDisplay.class);`

and make this  `super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);` first line of list item click method.

Comment: I dont think that will make a difference

Comment: I gave this a try and I did it with what the person above you said and it still didn't work

Comment: what error you are getting.?..either you have not attached listener to the list or may be there would a little silly mistakes.

Comment: I have not attached a listener. How do you reference the listview in a ListActivity?

Comment: oh. i guess you extends activity.do you have @override innotation above onListItemClick method, also place ' super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);' after opening bracket of onListItemClick method.

Comment: like this :  @Override
      protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
                        
                        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

Comment: My onListItemClick is overridden. I am extending ListActivity and from what I understand ListActivity only has one ListView, which is what is confusing me because I am not sure how exactly to reference it to add a listener...I will edit my question to add more code

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
this.startActivity(launchIntent);
```